# select2 apply entered text as tag before user choose it

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I use select2 `v4.0.7` with possibility to search by text (`tags: true`)

```
$query.select2({
    minimumInputLength: 2,
    ajax: {
        url: '/'+ LOCALE +'/search-suggest',
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 450,
        cache: true,
        data: function (params) {
            return {q: params.term}
        }
    },
    language: LOCALE,
    tags: true,
    data: selectData,
    allowClear: true,
    placeholder: ''
});
```

Catch some problem when I paste text with `Ctrl+v`. In this case select2 requests ajax url and apply WHOLE entered text. When I push `Enter` nothing  happens, cause tag text equal with entered text and `select2:select` doesn't fire.

How to stop auto applying the first result when input is empty and `tags` option is `true`?

Comment: when I enter by keyboard it asks by first 2-3 characters and apply them, after the next character the enter button works fine.

Answer (score 0):

1. remove `tags: true`, cause in apply text as result without firing any events.
2. add escaped user query as first result in ajax controller/url

   ```
   $queryToDisplay = 
       htmlspecialchars(
           strip_tags(
               stripslashes(
                   $queryOriginal
               )
           ),
           ENT_QUOTES
       )
   ;
   $this->data['results'][] = ['id' => $queryToDisplay, 'text' => $queryToDisplay];
   ```